# Rails polymorphic nested route generation fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Using rails 4.0.0, nested polymorphic route path (and URL) generation fails. IE:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :commentable, :polymorphic => true
end

class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments, :as => :commentable, :dependent => :destroy
end

class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments, :as => :commentable, :dependent => :destroy
end
```

The routes:

```
resources :articles, :except => [:destroy] do
  concerns :commentable
end

resources :images, :except => [:destroy] do
  concerns :commentable
end

concern :commentable do
  resources :comments, :only => [:create, :update, :show]
end
```

In the view somewhere:
(assume comment is a saved comment in the db)

```
= polymorphic_path([comment.commentable, comment])
```

Which should output something like (assuming comment.commentable is an Article):

```
/articles/1/comments/1
```

According to the comments in the PolymorphicRoutes module (actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/routing/polymorphic_routes.rb), this syntax should work (unless I'm reading it wrong).

```
#   polymorphic_url(post) # => "http://example.com/posts/1"
#   polymorphic_url([blog, post]) # => "http://example.com/blogs/1/posts/1"
#   polymorphic_url([:admin, blog, post]) # => "http://example.com/admin/blogs/1/posts/1"
#   polymorphic_url([user, :blog, post]) # => "http://example.com/users/1/blog/posts/1"
#   polymorphic_url(Comment) # => "http://example.com/comments"
```

Instead, I get this exception:

> ActionController::UrlGenerationError: No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"comments", :locale=>##, :id=>nil, :format=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]

Comment: What is the actual output of rake routes?  Specifically the routes related to your polymorphic models

Answer (score 0):

I have this in my comment model

```
    belongs_to :post
    belongs_to :commentable, :polymorphic => true   
    has_many :comments, :as => :commentable

    def post
     return @post if defined?(@post)
     @post = commentable.is_a?(Post) ? commentable : commentable.post
    end
```

In my post model

```
    has_many :comments, :as => :commentable, :dependent => :destroy
```

In my route file

```
    resources :posts do
     resources :comments
    end

    resources :comments do
     resources :comments
    end
```

You can take a look at this tutorial which helped me get it working with my site. There is a part one for the models and a part two for the controller and route. You will see the part 1 and 2 links at the top. Hope it helps!

http://kconrails.com/2010/10/23/nested-comments-in-ruby-on-rails-1-models/